# Have we found all the ways of studying the universe?

Tags: subjectivity

I have a question- have we found every single way of studying a particular thing? Like biology is a subject which deals with living organisms. Is there a possibility that there are some subjects that humanity has not found yet? I mean a new way of research, study and looking at things? Like nuclear energy was not a subject until it started in 1895 according to wiki.

Are there more subjects to be found that deal with other hidden aspects of this world? Or all ways have been found?

Comment: If we haven't found them yet how would we know for sure that they are out there? But given our history it is an almost sure bet that no, we did not find them all. But what more is there to it? The question as written has a trivial answer, but is that really what you meant to ask? If not, it is unclear what it is.

Comment: Yes. Just curious that is it not ignorance to know that there's no new way of scientific indulgence. Because as i confront so many questions that are asked here it creates a doubt that there is some kind of narrow mindedness in our approach. Which might be revealed in future. For modern science is not very old.

Comment: Glad you made it :) Don't forget to vote up helpful answers and comments. Also, if someone answers your question, select the answer by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your question equates "how to study" with "categories of study."

Biology does not necessarily study in a different **way**, we just call it "biology" because of **what** is studied.

As for the *way we study*, many subjects of study use the [scientific method](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scientific%20method), such as biology, physics, chemistry, etc. However, other subjects do not have experiments that are observable, measurable, and repeatable. For example, history would not be studied in the same **way** that biology or physics is studied.

You ask:

> 1) Is there a possibility that there are some subjects that humanity has not found yet?

and

> 2) I mean a new way of research, study and looking at things?

These are two different questions with two different answers:

> 1) **Yes**, there is certainly the possibility that we discover some totally new subject that we have never studied. Perhaps there is something hidden deep within the atom or in space that, once discovered, will open up a brand new field of study (just like your example about nuclear research).
>
> 2) **Yes, maybe**. People are quite fond of the scientific method. It produces results that seem quite accurate, and those results have been used to make accurate predictions and technological advances. Is there a "new way of research", besides those ways already used? It is possible, but it probably wouldn't be "found" in the same way that protons and electrons were "found."